# gong-wpf-dragdrop - Touch - Panning Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

So I had a problem with `gong-wpf-dragdrop` and touch. My `ScrollViewer` was taking the events. So I fixed it with `ScrollViewer.PanningMode=PanningMode.None`, but this disabled my `ScrollViewer` - so I made a workaround.

This behaviour checks if someone holds and presses his finger for the `PressTimeDuration`. If yes - it sets `ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None"`.

```
   public class ScrollViewerTouchBehaviour : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
        public TimeSpan PressHoldDuration { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5);

        private ScrollViewer CurrentScrollViewer { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AssociatedObject is ScrollViewer viewer) CurrentScrollViewer = viewer;
            else CurrentScrollViewer = AssociatedObject.GetDescendantByType<ScrollViewer>(); ;
            if (CurrentScrollViewer == null) return;

            CurrentScrollViewer.TouchDown += CurrentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchDown;
        }

    private async void CurrentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ScrollViewer viewer && await viewer.TouchHoldAsync(PressHoldDuration))
            viewer.PanningMode = PanningMode.None;
    }




        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
            CurrentScrollViewer.PreviewTouchDown -= CurrentScrollViewer_PreviewTouchDown;
            CurrentScrollViewer = null;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }
    }
```

(Other stuff will take care to reset the ScrollViewer back to `PanningMode="VerticalFirst";` after DragDrop is done.)

The function `TouchHoldAsync(TimeSpan timeToWait)` will check if the `ScrollViewer` is pressed for the `PressToHoldDuration`.

Now my problem is - I allways have to "enable" the `PanningMode=None` by touching it once - so the event gets fired. And then I can drag and drop on the second attempt.

So my code actually only switches the PanningMode on a long press and hold. In other words i just toggle between a "DragDropMode" and a ScrollMode.

So how can I make it happen that I dont have to touch twice and drag and drop directly?